# How to judge the ListView‘s firstItem complete shown?

Tags: android

I am make a Pull to Refresh, and I got a problem, I need to judge if the ListView scroll to the top. if ListView is Top, I pull down , Header will be pull down, If ListView is not top, I pull down, I need to let ListView to receive the MotionEvent, let top(first item can show completely).

I am using onScrollListener, it have bug, that is when the first item show a little(first item's bottom), the callback `onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount)` will give me the `firstVisible` is 0.

Comment: Would be better if you post code. Based on reading your question, I say you need to `getTop()` for the `firstVisible` and check if it is not off screen (`negative number`)

Comment: @AmulyaKhare Thank you~I will try your method

Comment: If it works.. let me know.. i will post this as an answer. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

use this [RefreshableListView](https://github.com/woozzu/RefreshableListView)

just add the custom listView class to your project...and implement on refresh listener...this is how i implemented...

Answer (score 0):

this is another nice [library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh). that you can apply in

```
ListView
ExpandableListView
GridView
WebView
ScrollView
HorizontalScrollView
ViewPager
```

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh